# Retrieve data from firebase from a specific child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the database I post below. I want to retrieve data from a specific child. In my case I want only the first child. Is there a way that I can do this? I also post the code that I use to retrieve data from firebase.

[image]

```
ArrayList<Double> gr, gr1;
databasePaths.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for (DataSnapshot items: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {

                info  = items.getValue(Paths.class);
                gr = info.ola;
                gr1 = info.ola1;

            }
```

Comment: To understand better, you want to get the data from the first child `-LmxF ... zeAA`, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes but it's ok i have found the answer. Thank you for replying.